# jQuery UI Accordion - Position Absolute, Bottom 0 With Overflow Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to figure out how to position my jQuery UI accordion with `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` whilst making the Accordion vertically scrollable, as the content will be larger than the viewport.

I've adapted a JSFiddle from elsewhere on StackOverflow to outline the basic issue. Currently if you turn off the absolute positioning of the `#accordion-outer` container the Accordion works as it should – i.e. auto scrolling to the top of the opened Accordion tab and allowing the content to be scrolled through.

It's this last part of positioning it at the bottom of the screen which has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a link to my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32v8bc54/

Thanks!